# Why does the official JVM documentation contradict its implementation in addShutdownHook?

Tags: java, jvm, shutdown, shutdown-hook

There's a bit of a clash for whether shutdown hooks, which are of class `Thread`, run their runnable code on the thread on which the shutdown was called, or run on themselves.

`addShutdownHook` takes a `Thread` as a parameter. This implies the thread will start and run its `run` method on itself.  This is also consistent with the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) for `addShutdownHook`:

> public void addShutdownHook(Thread hook)
>
> Registers a new virtual-machine shutdown hook.
>   The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.
>
> A shutdown hook is simply an initialized but unstarted thread. When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and **let them run concurrently**. When all the hooks have finished it will then run all uninvoked finalizers if finalization-on-exit has been enabled. Finally, the virtual machine will halt. Note that daemon threads will continue to run during the shutdown sequence, as will non-daemon threads if shutdown was initiated by invoking the exit method.

(Emphasis mine)

However, the code is [as follows](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Shutdown.java#Shutdown.runHooks%28%29):

```
/* Run all registered shutdown hooks
 */
private static void runHooks() {
    for (int i=0; i < MAX_SYSTEM_HOOKS; i++) {
        try {
            Runnable hook;
            synchronized (lock) {
                // acquire the lock to make sure the hook registered during
                // shutdown is visible here.
                currentRunningHook = i;
                hook = hooks[i];
            }
            if (hook != null) hook.run();  // not Thread.start - Runnable.run (!!)
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            if (t instanceof ThreadDeath) {
                ThreadDeath td = (ThreadDeath)t;
                throw td;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(`!!` comment mine)

Note this is [little changed](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Shutdown.java#Shutdown.runHooks%28%29) from JDK 6, which makes the problem all the clearer:

```
/* Run all registered shutdown hooks
 */
private static void runHooks() {
    /* We needn't bother acquiring the lock just to read the hooks field,
     * since the hooks can't be modified once shutdown is in progress
     */
    for (Runnable hook : hooks) {
        try {
            hook.run();
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            if (t instanceof ThreadDeath) {
                ThreadDeath td = (ThreadDeath)t;
                throw td;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought I was reading this wrong and calling `run` magically started the thread.  But it doesn't.  I wrote the `run` code myself.  That code does not start a thread (in the case of a `Thread`, it's natural and correct to assume `run` runs on the thread.)

So something is *really wrong* here.  Is it the Javadoc and the signature of the `addShutdownHook` method, which per the code should *not* be taking a thread, but a runnable? Is it the implementation? Or is it the more likely culprit - me; and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing `Shutdown.runHooks()` and `ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks()`. The shutdown hooks you register with `Runtime` are registered with `ApplicationShutdownHooks`, which itself registers a `Runnable` as a `Shutdown` hook

```
static {
    try {
        Shutdown.add(1 /* shutdown hook invocation order */,
            false /* not registered if shutdown in progress */,
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runHooks(); // (!!)  your hooks
                }
            }
        );
        hooks = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // application shutdown hooks cannot be added if
        // shutdown is in progress.
        hooks = null;
    }
}
```

The shutdown hooks are ran concurrently

```
static void runHooks() { // In ApplicationShutdownHooks
    Collection<Thread> threads;
    synchronized(ApplicationShutdownHooks.class) {
        threads = hooks.keySet();
        hooks = null;
    }

    for (Thread hook : threads) { // (!!) your hooks
        hook.start();
    }
    for (Thread hook : threads) {
        try {
            hook.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) { }
    }
}
```

For reference, the (oracle jdk7) code for `Runtime#addShutdownHook(Thread)`.

```
public void addShutdownHook(Thread hook) {
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
        sm.checkPermission(new RuntimePermission("shutdownHooks"));
    }
    ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(hook);
}
```