# What happens if System.exit is called from a shutdown hook?

Tags: java, shutdown, shutdown-hook

I have a rather complicated shutdown in Java - there's a lot of clean up work to do.  In particular I'm trying to figure out how to error handle from a shutdown hook thread.  My code includes this currently:

```
try {
    return shutdownPromise = doShutdown();
}
catch (Throwable exc) {
    logger.error("An exception was thrown while shutting down the application.", exc);  
    System.exit(1);
    return null;
}
```

When I originally wrote this I essentially thought, an error in shutdown should just go straight to `exit`. But `exit` is not so low level; it calls the shutdown hooks.

So I thought -

1. What does calling exit from a shutdown hook do?
2. What is the right way to error handle from a shutdown hook?

Comment: @libik Why not? That's actually encouraged, to share knowledge. In fact, there's a checkbox specifically saying "answer your own question."

Comment: It's a nice answer; worth an upvote.

Comment: Well yes but as long as you really ask the question and you figure it out yourself or with help of others... Not to ask question and answer before anybody has any response.

Comment: @libik: Wrong.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firstly, the easy answer:  your process deadlocks.

System.exit winds up calling `Shutdown.exit`, which ends with [this code block](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Shutdown.java#Shutdown.exit%28int%29):

```
synchronized (Shutdown.class) {
     /* Synchronize on the class object, causing any other thread
      * that attempts to initiate shutdown to stall indefinitely
      */
     sequence();
     halt(status);
}
```

The comment is completely accurate.  But to understand this we need to see exactly what the the shutdown hook does.

Shutdown hooks are added via `ApplicationShutdownHooks.add`, as explained in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19550623/1339987).  Note that the `sequence` method above eventually winds up on [this line of code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Shutdown.java#Shutdown.runHooks%28%29) in `Shutdown.runHooks`:

```
if (hook != null) hook.run();
```

Firstly, note these hooks are *not* your application shutdown hooks.  They are system shutdown hooks, which are different, and one of them is responsible for ensuring your application shutdown hooks run.  Notice that is *run*, not *start*. In other words, it *blocks*.  One of these shutdown hooks will be a system hook that concurrently starts all the application shutdown hooks (you can trace this code for yourself or in linked answer), then blocks until they all complete using a `Thread.join` call.  One of these will be your application shutdown hook - which, if it calls `System.exit`, will be waiting to get the lock on `Shutdown.class` forever.

Next, the dumb answer:  call `Runtime.getRuntime().halt()` instead.  I say "the dumb answer" because this is probably the slightly lower level thing you were looking to do instead of exit.  If `System.exit` represents a clean shutdown that failed, then `halt` is a hard shutdown that will always succeed immediately.

Next, the smarter answer:  probably nothing.  Just let your shutdown hook finish, for the following reasons. Your shutdown hook does not own the shutdown - in particular, there may be other shutdown hooks that need to do their work.  Conversely, I suspect one of the responsibilities of this hook is to force a hard shutdown eventually.  I would recommend creating that as a delayed task right away then letter this hook complete normally.

Comment: I had the pleasure to learn that the hard way. Here is the case study if anyone is interested:
https://knotgillcup.blogspot.com/2019/08/systemexit-not-working.html