# Java process in docker container always ends with status 137 after docker stop

Tags: java, docker

I have a java process started with script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java $JAVA_OPTS -cp "lib/*" com.example.Launcher
```

To assert clean jetty shutdown, I've added the following shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    LOGGER.info("SIGTERM received");
    try
    {
      jettyServer.stop();
      LOGGER.info("Shutdown completed");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
}));
```

I see in logs, `SIGTERM received` and `Shutdown completed`, nevertheless, `docker inspect` always shown status 137.

I've recently added `System.exit(0)`, but this haven't changed anything.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the memory settings like Xmx and Xms?

Comment: @PrateekJain high enough, so that the actual values are much lower. OutOfMemory was also my first thought, but the log that appears after Jetty shutdown suggests for me, the shutdown was clean

Comment: Could there be a lag b/w shutdown command and its actual shutdown? I suspect that jetty wasn't fully shutdown but script got completed and docker killed container. Try to put a sleep before system.exit.

Comment: Agree, looks like the container gets killed due to graceful stop timeout - this ends up in exit code 137. Check docker logs (`jounalctl -eu docker`) for messages like `Container $CONTAINER_ID failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force`.

Comment: @PrateekJain after some search after your hint, it seems to be a bug in Jetty: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1549

Comment: Hmm I've replaced System.exit() with Runtime.getRuntime().halt(), as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552358/what-happens-if-system-exit-is-called-from-a-shutdown-hook and it seems to work...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because out of memory.
In the official document, there is resolution.
https://success.docker.com/article/what-causes-a-container-to-exit-with-code-137

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not provide any shutdown hook for graceful shutdown of application. If you want to stop container after your application process end then you can provide sleep duration before SIGKILL signal trigger *docker stop --time=30* .  [You can also trigger your application shutdown trigger from docker entrypoint](https://milesmaddox.com/2016/10/31/Docker_Shutdown_Hooks/)

Comment: [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) sends SIGTERM, then after a delay (default 10 seconds), it sends SIGKILL.  That looks like what the code in the question is trying to hook into.